# Как обойти NAT, без услуг вспомогательного сервера?

Tags: ip, nat

Существует ли возможность установить связь с компьютером, находящимся за NAT, без помощи вспомогательного сервера, типа TURN, зная IP адрес провайдера и IP адрес компьютера в локальной сети? Если такая возможность существует, то каким образом?

Comment: знание только адресов ничего не даст. проходить nat можно  различными способами, но все они работают изнутри, а не снаружи

Comment: Я не специалист по сетям, но интернет это 256 протоколов. Может быть все-же есть какой либо способ, не из нутри? Например, определить внутрениий адрес по порту NAT вполне возможно.

Comment: ну 256 это вы загнули, по факту порты есть только 2 х протоколах tcp и udp. и только они нормально NAT'ятся. с остальными есть некоторые нюансы и то их десяток и мы их не рассматриваем. Но природа NAT такова, что пропустить пакет внутрь только если на момент прихода этого пакета в таблице NAT есть подходящая запись (поры/ip). А новые записи в таблице появляются как реакция на пакеты изнутри сети и более никак. И все известные способы обхода nat как раз и рассчитаны на добавление такой записи. P.S. первый раз слышу что бы по номеру порта можно было что то вычислить, они обычно случайны

Comment: @Mike Посмотрите здесь: http://www.whatsmyip.org/more-info-about-you/

Comment: И что ? локальный ip получается JS скриптом на стороне клиента, прямо в вашем браузере и тут же вписывается в страницу. Если ваш браузер не будет поддерживать rtcpeerconnection то ничего тот сайт не узнает. И к NAT это не имеет ни малейшего отношения

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: А что касается протоколов взгляните, пожалуйста, сюда: https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.txt

Comment: базовый NAT поддерживает только 1,6 и 17. все остальные делаются в случае необходимости, дополнительными модулями nat и их рассматривать вообще нет смысла потому, что используются они очень редко и только для очень специфических задач. Большую часть из них невозможно NAT'ить в принципе

Comment: Дело не в NAT. Может быть есть, какой нибудь, туннель, который использует  внутренний IP адрес, для установления связи?

Comment: внутренние ip в интернете не маршрутизируются. Единственный способ задать ip, не маршрутизуемый в интернете и получить к нему доступ является передать этот Ip внутри некого протокола на сервер который подключен к интернету и при этом видит цель по внутреннему ip. таких протоколов довольно много, начиная от SOCKS (и кстати никакого отношения к тем 256 они не имеют, потому что это протоколы уровня tcp или udp). НО на сервере делающим NAT должна быть установлена соответствующая служба, которая поймет этот протокол и передаст запрос дальше. На подавляющем числе серверов этого нет

Comment: Т.е. все зависит от провайдера? ... Ну да. Интренет это же, что-бы Ютуб смотреть, а не показания датчиков. Спасибо.

Comment: @Mike где можно с вами связаться? нужна маленькая помощь с NAT, хочу запустить у себя на компе сервер онлайн игры, раньше провайдер выдавал белый ип, теперь серый и изменить это можно лишь доплатив сверху провайдеру, а так же Hamachi и no-ip не вариант.

Comment: Есть такая статья: https://habr.com/ru/post/509730/ Случай, конечно, не ваш, но это явно показывает, что связь двух компов, оба из которых находятся каждый за своим NAT'ом - вполне возможна.